# iOS, how to continuously animate a line "running" ("marching ants" effect)?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I must admit I have no clue how to do this in iOS -

Here's some code that makes a nice dotted line:

[image]

Now, I want that line to "run" upwards:

So, every one second it will move upwards by, `itemLength * 2.0`.

Of course, it would wrap around top to bottom.

So, `DottedVertical` should just do this completely on its own.

Really, how do you do this in iOS?

It would be great if the solution is general and will "scroll" any I suppose layer or drawn thing.

In say a game engine it's trivial, you just animate the offset of the texture. Can you perhaps offset the layer, or something, in iOS?

What's the best way?

I guess you'd want to use the GPU (layer animation right?) to avoid melting the cpu.

```
@IBDesignable class DottedVertical: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = UIColor.faveColor

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // say you want 8 dots, with perfect fenceposting:
        let totalCount = 8 + 8 - 1
        let fullHeight = bounds.size.height
        let width = bounds.size.width
        let itemLength = fullHeight / CGFloat(totalCount)
        let beginFromTop = !lowerHalfOnly ? 0.0 : (fullHeight * 8.0 / 15.0)
        let top = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: beginFromTop)
        let bottom = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: fullHeight)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: top)
        path.addLine(to: bottom)
        path.lineWidth = width
        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [itemLength, itemLength]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
        dotColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
}
```

*(Bonus - if you had a few of these on screen, they'd have to be synced of course. There'd need to be a "sync" call that starts the running animation, so you can start them all at once with a notification or other message.)*

Comment: CAEmitterLayer?

Comment: I think you could create a `CAShapeLayer` and animate its `lineDashPhase`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a "marching ants" effect – Apple actually gives you sample code for this in the docs for `CAShapeLayer`'s [`lineDashPhase`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521856-linedashphase) :)

Comment: Ah!  phase is exactly what's needed: awesome.  And I had no clue you could "add" an animation in that way - spectacular!  Thanks men !  :)

Comment: **CAEmitterLayer** - fantastic!  who needs Unity.  great tip, i knew nothing about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, here's a copy and paste solution based on the Men's suggestions above!

Good one!  Superb effect...

```
@IBDesignable class DottedVertical: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = sfBlack6 { didSet {setup()} }

    override func layoutSubviews() { setup() }

    var s:CAShapeLayer? = nil

    func setup() {
        // say you want 8 dots, with perfect fenceposting:
        - calculate exactly as in the example in the question above -

        // marching ants...

        if (s == nil) {
            s = CAShapeLayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(s!)
        }

        s!.strokeColor = dotColor.cgColor
        s!.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
        s!.lineWidth = width
        let ns = NSNumber(value: Double(itemLength))
        s!.lineDashPattern = [ns, ns]

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [top, bottom])
        s!.path = path

        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
        anim.fromValue = 0
        anim.toValue = ns + ns
        anim.duration = 1.75 // seconds
        anim.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude

        s!.add(anim, forKey: nil)

        self.layer.addSublayer(s!)
    }
}
```