# How to create a complete marching ants border effect with freedom of choosing any width for dash?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using down code for creating my marching ants border effect, the issue is here that the marching will be not complete correctly if I choose dashWidth bigger than 20.0, as you can see I want my dashWidth be 40.0 but as you see the result is not good. what is the formula to make any dashWidth marchable?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dashWidth: CGFloat = 40.0
    @State private var toggleClockwise: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("dashWidth: " + String(describing: Int(dashWidth))).bold()
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0, lineCap: .round, dash: [dashWidth], dashPhase: toggleClockwise ? -2.0*dashWidth : .zero))
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .onAppear() { toggleClockwise.toggle() }
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: toggleClockwise)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS, how to continuously animate a line "running" ("marching ants" effect)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936819/ios-how-to-continuously-animate-a-line-running-marching-ants-effect)

Comment: Maybe have a circular background that looks like an asterisk `✱` and continuously rotate it, then overlay a bordered rectangle as a mask

Comment: @aheze: I found that if we use `cornerRadius = 0.0` it would solve the issue! with that said I could use even `dashWidth = 100.0` , but I need cornerRadius in my code.